# Make a Chrome app that opens in a new window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, new-window

I thought it would be cool and easy to make a game in a chrome app, but I wan't my app to open in a new window, like [Spelunky HTML5](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spelunky-html5/mhagnkphcmpkmabhocgimoncfaihkpof?hl=en). Here is a picture of what it looks like: [image: Spelunky HTML%]

The app is run in a unique chrome window, and it is made with HTML5. Is there any way to do this with manifest.json? If not, I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create):

```js
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    id: "MyApp",
    outerBounds: {width: 500, height: 300}
});
```

Make sure to examine the official [step-by-step tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) and the [demo app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/hello-world).

Comment: funny, I had the demo app page open in a separate tab when I posted this question, but I didn't care to look at it until this morning, thanks!